# send command from server to client vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, networking, server, client

i want to build a server client application using vb. 
how can i send or call the form to other pc client using vb
ex. 
click button then the form open in client

sorry for bad English

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can get help with **specific** programming related questions. Therefore you must in most cases show your research and attempts in solving the problem. As it stands this question is too broad because there are too many ways to achieve your goal. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You can check out the [**TcpClient**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**TcpListener**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) classes on the MSDN documentation, they include some examples. You can also Google for additional tutorials using them.